# Docker-compose is not generating log file for spring boot application

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, microservices

We are developed a project which has multiple micro-service developed on spring boot.We are using docker container and docker-compose.We are facing issue in generating the application log file.We have written below config in application.yml file.

logging:
    file: /data/test/run/logs/x.log

After generating the image if we start a container seperatly(using docker run imageName) log file is generated in container.But when we up our containers using docker-compose(docker-compose up) same images,log file is not being generating in container.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  lb:
   image: dockercloud/haproxy
   links:
     - x-service
   volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "1936:1936"

  eureka-service:
    image: x.y.com/registration-server:0.0.2
    ports:
     - "2323:2323"
    environment:
     - APPBINARY=registration-server.jar
    entrypoint:
     - /usr/bin/jarrun.sh
     - QA

  x-service:
    image: x.y.com/x-service:0.2.7
    ports:
     - "4444"
    links:
     - eureka-service
    environment:
     - JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M
     - VIRTUAL_HOST=*/x/*
     - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=qa"
     - APPBINARY=x-service.jar
     - environment=qa
    extra_hosts:
    - "service1.test.com:111.11.1.111"
    entrypoint:
     - /usr/bin/jarrun.sh
     - QA
```

Comment: Post Dockerfiles, compose files, how you start docker & compose etc... please :)

Comment: I have updated the question.we are doing docker-compose up

Comment: also post the docker run command you use to start the individual container. it is most probably a case where you have to explicitly let your app know the path where it has to write its log file (may be a missing cli argument in your entry point scripts ?)